# Azure blob Storage: Missing CONTENT-MD5 when blob uploaded using cloudBlockBlob.uploadBlock Java API

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm uploading files in AZURE blob storage using azure-storage java sdk version 8.6.5. If I upload a file from Web Console, I see Content-MD5 value.

But I do not see **CONTENT-MD5** value when I upload using the following sample code :-

```
BlobRequestOptions blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
blobRequestOptions.setStoreBlobContentMD5(true);  
cloudBlockBlob.uploadBlock(blockId, inputstream , length, null, blobRequestOptions, null);
```

File is split into multiple chunks and uploaded in multiple parallel threads and finally committing the block list as follows. File upload is working fine.

```
cloudBlockBlob.commitBlockList(blockIds, null, blobRequestOptions, null);
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Also any ideas what is the best way to check the file integrity programmatically and to ensure file is uploaded correctly if content-MD5 is not available. Does Azure blob Storage support any thing for content verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `CONTENT-MD5` value after you have uploaded a file successfully,just try the code below :

```
cloudBlockBlob.getProperties().getContentMD5()
```

If you are still missing the content-MD5 value, [this link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/495) could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this code and I am getting NULL value for ContentMD5, whereas other properties like size, Etag etc have correct values.

Comment: @Arti, I see, seems here is the same issue that you are faceing: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/495

Comment: Thanks @Stanley. The link shared is helpful

Comment: Hi @Arti,glad to know this link is helpful. I have edited my answer, please accept it so that it could help others and close this question :)